# Is there a ttk equivalent of Scrolledtext widget Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-scrolledtext

I set the theme of my main window to an awtheme 'awdark'.All the widgets with ttk extension set its appearance according to the theme by itself all except for the scrolled text widget which appears white in colour(i.e, color of the field as well as the color and look of the scrollbar)probably because its not a part of ttk.My scrolledtext widget is contained in a ttk.Frame widget by the way.Is there any workaround this?

Comment: Can't you just change the color of the text widget to match your theme?

Comment: Its not the color of the text thats bothering me but the color of the scrollbar.It is white and it is supposed to be a blue color

Comment: Is there any way to change the color of the scrolbar of a scrolledTextwidget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a ttk equivalent of Scrolledtext widget Tkinter

No, there is not. The ttk widgets don't have a text widget.

The scrolledtext widget is just a text widget and scrollbars, there's not much more to it. You can create your own which uses ttk scrollbars with just a few lines of code.

Here's a solution that doesn't use classes. One that is class-based is just a couple extra lines of code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text = tk.Text(frame, wrap="none")
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, command=text.yview, orient="vertical")
hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, command=text.xview, orient="horizontal")
text.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, xscrollcommand=hsb.set)

frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you sir for this code,it helped me but can I also change the color of the cursor as well tow white

Comment: @Ironman: Yes, the color of the cursor is configurable with the `insertbackground` option.

Comment: Thanks once again

Comment: @BryanOakley This is nice, but when I want to make a class that behaves like ScrolledText (by just inheriting from tkinter.Text) I can't just grid or pack things in the constructor. Can you help with code for this case?

Comment: @petro4213: don't inherit from a `Text` widget. Instead, inherit from a `Frame`. That will allow you to place both scrollbars and the text widget together.

Comment: @BryanOakley But then I have to duplicate all methods the Text widget has and redirect them to the Text widget, which then is kind of a sub-widget, but not the base class anymore. In Perl/Tk there's the concept of a "MegaWidget", which allows for constructing compound widgets from basic widgets packed or gridded into some layout. There you can specify which methods are delegated to which sub-widget. I couldn't find anything similar in tkinter and Pwm looks more like a coterie to me.

Comment: @petro4213: "duplicating the methods" takes probably less than a dozen lines of code.

Comment: @BryanOakley This maybe right for a specific widget, but it is not very elegant and certainly not what object oriented programming is all about... I think I'll just use a Text widget as base class and add the scrollbars externally - also ugly, but not that much...

Comment: @petro4213: this has nothing to do with elegance or object oriented programming. You can inherit from text if you want, but putting scrollbars inside the text widget will overlap some of the text. Combining three objects inside a fourth is  called composition, and it's a common object-oriented pattern.